Virtual repository returns 404 error while fetching for file for the first time [it checks remote repo first instead of local one]
I have weird situation while working with my virtual repo. It happens during my github workflow execution, but I tested it also locally and got same behavior. Let's start from artifactory, so I use virtual repo with repoA (local repo) and repoB (remote repo). In advance settings repoA is listed first. While building some application/creating docker image I fetch for some packageX from my virtual repo. packageX is located in repoA. I ma getting 404 error for packageA. In artifactory access.log I can see that it sent request to repoB (there is no packageA so 404 error is right). Then I fetch one more time for packageA and get 200, package found and downloaded. In artifactory access.log there is no information about fetching from repoB, so it did fetch directly from repoA.
Similar situation happens when I ask for different package... first fetch 404, after that 200.
Do you have any idea why it looks for packageA in repoB (remote repo) first? How can I change it and get rid of this 404 error???
Ps. While testing for fetching actions I used simple curl. If it might be useful, I tested it on some .zip file.
Fetch package from virtual repo. I expect to get 200 every single time instead of returning 404 for first fetch.

There are a few things to check from the local repository's aspect. Is the artifact available in the local repo and downloadable through the UI directly? How about a cURL request against that package and parallelly review the artifactory.log (For Artifactory 6.X versions) for any error messages returned. Recalculate the metadata against the local and see if it works as expected.

HI @Yuvarajan first of all, thanks for answer :)

Yes local repo is downloadable through the UI.
I did test it with curl and as I described similar situation. First curl returned 404 ( I also saw in logs that it was looking for package in remote repo instead of local). Second curl returned 200 (I saw in logs that it was looking in local repo this time).

